# Logic for Application Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make an ActiveRecord call to get information for the application layout (the default application.html.haml layout). I know I am not supposed to put logic into the layout itself, but I am unsure of where to put it.

The line of code I need run in the layout is just a simple Model call:

```
Client.find_by(:id => current_user.client_id)
```

Comment: application_controller?

Comment: I tried putting it into the application controller, but that doesn't work the same as the other controllers.

Comment: Can you add what kind of information you're looking for?

Comment: @hlee Post the code you've tried, both the ApplicationController and the code you've tried in the layout. There is no reason not to put code in your layout, it's the best place for "Currently logged in as" etc, for example.

Comment: By the way, it looks like there's a 1:M relationship between your `User` and `Client` classes. If you set up the proper `belongs_to` / `has_many` lines, you don't need to do `find_by`. You could simply do `current_user.client`, which may look a little nicer to you in the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest throwing it in `helpers/application_helper.rb`. I've used this in the past for things such as title helpers and body class helpers.

```
# helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def body_class
    [controller_name, action_name].join(' ')
  end
end

# views/layouts/application.slim
body class=body_class
  = yield
```

The `ApplicationController` isn't for such helpers. It's mainly as support for your controllers, not your views.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I guess I was just stuck in the mindset that any sort of Model call should always go in a controller. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @hlee how you access this data is mostly down to preference. Every time you ask the question, you'll receive different answers. I agree with Paul; with correct associations setup in your models, you can do `current_user.client`, which might avoid the helper in the first place. You can also have controller specific helpers, such as `helpers/users_helper.rb` which will only be available in the views for the users controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay if you put it in ApplicationController. And you can put controller related code to `controllers/concerns` folder.

'concerns/concern.rb':

```
module Concern
  def method
    # Your code here
  end
end
```

To use a module from concerns folder include it in the controller: `include Concern`

Comment: He is trying to replace logic in his layout with a helper method. Methods in your controller or `ApplicationController` are not available in the view.

Comment: @DamienRoche Yes, you're right. But still it's possible to access instance variables from your ApplicationController defined in a method which is called through `before_action` callback. The helper would be an appropriate place for such code.

Comment: @DamienRoche It seems pretty unclear *what* OP is trying to do, lacking code or enough words to describe it...

Comment: @ABMagil they are trying to avoid putting logic into the layout. Without code, I'll just deal with that.